# NETWORK_PROVIDER not worked in android versions 4.0 & above / API level 14 & above

Tags: android

In android 4.0 & above a call to

LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener)

is giving exception as

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network.

Even if the network is enabled, the same exception occurs.

I know this is a reported issue (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19857).

My question is.

**How to get location by network provider or any other method (not GPS) in android 4.0 & above ?**

Answer (score 1):

There is a open issue of android 4.0 framework , so network provider is not working but latest android version it had resolved and successful working ,Please check your code in latest android framework.

Comment: Can you provide link of this issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use direct provider strings, as it is not guaranteed that it will exist at runtime.

Use only providers that you get from the LocationManager, like this:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE );
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider( criteria, true );

    if ( provider == null ) {
        Log.e( TAG, "No location provider found!" );
        return;
    }

    lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this support is available with newer version you can check..