# NETWORK_PROVIDER not returned or working

Tags: android, networking, location, location-provider

I want to locate the current place of the device wherever it is. The code below works fine outdoors, but no updates are notified indoors.

The code below can't access NETWORK_PROVIDER, only GPS_PROVIDER and PASSIVE_PROVIDER are returned, why? Other apps in the same device can locate my position indoors.

```
if ( mLocationManager==null )
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Location l;
for ( String provider : mLocationManager.getAllProviders() ){
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, locationListener);
    l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if ( isBetterLocation(l, currentBestLocation) )
    currentBestLocation = l;
}
```

when I change it to hard-coded NETWORK_PROVIDER:

```
    if ( mLocationManager==null )
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Location l;
List<String> providers = new ArrayList<String>();
providers.add(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
providers.add(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
//  for ( String provider : mLocationManager.getAllProviders() ){
for ( String provider : providers ){
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, locationListener);
    l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if ( isBetterLocation(l, currentBestLocation) )
    currentBestLocation = l;
}
```

the following exception is thrown:

```
11-17 14:06:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(7896): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
```

Comment: WLAN-assisted location is enabled in Settings, but mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) returns **false**. While other apps in the same device can locate correctly. I dont think it a dup to other questions, no answer for now, the device is Motorola XT928, reboot cant help. Either switching to Google Play Service helps, since many devices in this region Google Play is disabled.

Comment: maybe same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040048/network-provider-not-worked-in-android-versions-4-0-above-api-level-14-abo), which has no explicit answer.

Comment: Do you have an Internet connection? You need Internet access to get a nwetwork-based location

Comment: yes, sure. Some developers found it on Android 4.0+ but provided no explicit answer. Without OS updates, some other apps on the same device can locate correctly, so I think there is a programming way to make it.